# encrypted db snapshot restore from S3 not working AWS RDS(mysql) console

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-rds

I've an encrypted database snapshot that was generated through the AWS RDS console in an S3 bucket. When I attempted to restore the dB snapshot from S3, I received an error saying "Files from the specified Amazon S3 bucket are encrypted." Restoring from encrypted S3 object is not available". If restoring from an encrypted backup from S3 isn't allowed, why did AWS give us the option of backing up with an encryption key?

Is there a way to recover the data from the S3 bucket to a new database? Please provide me with recommendations on how to restore this encrypted database?

I need to restore the encrypted DB snapshot from s3 to rds in the AWS console.